# Rare crash when using fragments with unique id's

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a very unusual crash that happens maybe once a month or so.  There doesn't seem to be any rhyme or reason to it.  This is part of a large project, and since I'm not sure where exactly the problem is originating, I'm not sure which portions of code to paste here.  So instead I will just describe what I am doing, and I think might be causing the crash.

I have an activity with many nested fragments that I manage with the FragmentManager.  Because the nested fragments can be of the same type, I have to give the root view of each fragment a unique ID.  The app is crashing when calling super.onResume, and that call is the very first line of my overloaded onResume function (so my code is never given the chance to mess anything up).  The reason I think it is crashing due to the unique fragment id's is because I started having this problem after moving to unique id's, and the crash always references a low number resource id.

This error seems to be being thrown in the framework itself, so I'm not sure there is anything I can do about it.  Has anyone else come across this, and have the figured out a solution for it?  Or alternatively, does anyone know if you can surround super.onResume with a try/catch block?  I'm not sure whether the app would be able to recover at that point, and there does not seem to be any way to consistently reproduce this error in order to test it.

```
01-24 20:55:09.602 E/AndroidRuntime( 8156): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-24 20:55:09.602 E/AndroidRuntime( 8156): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {github.daneren2005.dsub/github.daneren2005.dsub.activity.SubsonicFragmentActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x2
01-24 20:55:09.602 E/AndroidRuntime( 8156):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3014)
01-24 20:55:09.602 E/AndroidRuntime( 8156):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3055)
01-24 20:55:09.602 E/AndroidRuntime( 8156):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
01-24 20:55:09.602 E/AndroidRuntime( 8156):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
01-24 20:55:09.602 E/AndroidRuntime( 8156):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331)
01-24 20:55:09.602 E/AndroidRuntime( 8156):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-24 20:55:09.602 E/AndroidRuntime( 8156):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
01-24 20:55:09.602 E/AndroidRuntime( 8156):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5454)
01-24 20:55:09.602 E/AndroidRuntime( 8156):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-24 20:55:09.602 E/AndroidRuntime( 8156):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-24 20:55:09.602 E/AndroidRuntime( 8156):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
01-24 20:55:09.602 E/AndroidRuntime( 8156):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
01-24 20:55:09.602 E/AndroidRuntime( 8156):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-24 20:55:09.602 E/AndroidRuntime( 8156): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x2
01-24 20:55:09.602 E/AndroidRuntime( 8156):     at android.content.res.Resources.getResourceName(Resources.java:1666)
01-24 20:55:09.602 E/AndroidRuntime( 8156):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:919)
01-24 20:55:09.602 E/AndroidRuntime( 8156):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
01-24 20:55:09.602 E/AndroidRuntime( 8156):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
01-24 20:55:09.602 E/AndroidRuntime( 8156):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
01-24 20:55:09.602 E/AndroidRuntime( 8156):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onResume(FragmentActivity.java:445)
01-24 20:55:09.602 E/AndroidRuntime( 8156):     at github.daneren2005.dsub.activity.SubsonicActivity.onResume(SubsonicActivity.java:130)
01-24 20:55:09.602 E/AndroidRuntime( 8156):     at github.daneren2005.dsub.activity.SubsonicFragmentActivity.onResume(SubsonicFragmentActivity.java:250)
01-24 20:55:09.602 E/AndroidRuntime( 8156):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1266)
01-24 20:55:09.602 E/AndroidRuntime( 8156):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5148)
01-24 20:55:09.602 E/AndroidRuntime( 8156):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2997)
01-24 20:55:09.602 E/AndroidRuntime( 8156):     ... 12 more
01-24 20:55:09.602 W/ActivityManager(  596):   Force finishing activity github.daneren2005.dsub/.activity.SubsonicFragmentActivity
```

Edit: Added unique id generation.  In onCreateView I use rootView.setId(rootId):

```
    public SelectDirectoryFragment() {
        super();
        rootId = getNewId();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        if(bundle != null) {
            int tmp = bundle.getInt(Constants.FRAGMENT_ID, -1);
            if(tmp > 0) {
                rootId = tmp;
            }
            entries = (List<MusicDirectory.Entry>) bundle.getSerializable(Constants.FRAGMENT_LIST);
            restoredInstance = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(Constants.FRAGMENT_ID, rootId);
        outState.putSerializable(Constants.FRAGMENT_LIST, (Serializable) entries);
    }

    protected int getNewId() {
        for (;;) {
            final int result = nextGeneratedId.get();
            // aapt-generated IDs have the high byte nonzero; clamp to the range under that.
            int newValue = result + 1;
            if (newValue > 0x00FFFFFF) newValue = 1; // Roll over to 1, not 0.
            if (nextGeneratedId.compareAndSet(result, newValue)) {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check anywhere in your Fragment or Activity that you might be doing a `setText()` call. It's possible you're trying to set the text to the `String.valueOf()` value of an integer, but `setText()` also has an overload which takes an integer *resource* value (e.g. R.string.my_string). I've seen this crash when I mistakenly did something like the following:

```
int myCount = doSomeCalculation();
textView.setText(myCount);
```

This will internally try to resolve `myCount` as a resource (e.g. `getString(myCount)`) rather than setting the text to the string value of the `myCount` variable.

**EDIT: Wait, how are you setting this unique ID on your Fragment's root?**

Comment: Wouldn't that cause a crash when the text is set, not later when it is resumed?  I will look for cases of that either way. I updated with the code you requested.

Comment: From what I can see, I imagine the issue is that you're changing the ID of the View post-creation, and after it tries to restore that state (after re-creating the View) it has the original ID in it, and cannot restore the state. 

If you just need to add multiple Fragments of the same type to a layout, I would suggest (unless I'm missing something in your implementation) that you simply use tags instead of modifying the view ID. When you add the fragment (`FragmentTransaction#add(int containerId, Fragment toAdd, String tag)`) set a unique *tag* to the Fragment to retrieve it later.

Comment: The problem I was running into was that when adding, I needed a unique ID to reference in the transaction.add.  If all the fragments had the same ID, it would add the fragment to the top level fragment and you would end up with both of them visible at the same time.  I at one point was fixing this by adding a lot of hacky code to hide the non-visible fragments, but that led to other issues.  This solution just seemed more elegent, so I was hoping there was a way to fix this solution instead of going back.

Comment: It sounds like you should just use `replace()` instead of `add()`.

Comment: That actually might be the case now.  At the time I was developing all these work arounds I was using several tabs with each one having nested fragments, and using replace caused all sorts of issues that there didn't seem to be any work around for.  I will try going to just using replace and see if that works now that I have a much simpler setup using the pull out drawer.